# Qual Estrutura/Papel de um Web Service?

Tags: php, web-service, mvc

Tenho um projeto no qual devo criar um site e um aplicativo (Intel XDK) do mesmo, pensei que seria mais ideal ter um 'núcleo' da aplicação em si para fazer a comunicação do banco de dados, assim no site só ir requisitando os dados por PHP e no aplicativo requisitar por Ajax.

Sei um pouco do conceito de Web Service, pelo que entendo, o Web Service poderia ser esse 'núcleo', mas nunca fiz um, não sei a estrutura de um e nem sei se é esse mesmo o objetivo de um Web Service.

Realmente seria ideal o uso dele? Ou seria melhor um Model compartilhado?

Pesquisei bastante sobre Web Service só que não consegui entender como ele é estruturado, alguém poderia indicar ou mostrar um exemplo simples para que possa iniciar a base do meu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei exatamente quais seriam essas requisições, mas creio que um WebService iria atender seu objetivo.

Como o nome diz um WebService é um serviço que roda na Web com o objetivo de prover informações a todos os clientes que solicitarem. A estrutura é simples: um servidor com acesso externo e com conexão ao outro servidor de bancos de dados. O serviço roda no servidor que pode ser acessado externamente pelo endereço e portas especificados. As rotinas do WebService recebe as requisições, faz as consultas no banco, empacota os dados - geralmente em JSON - e devolve ao cliente.

Tem vários exemplos na Web utilizando a tecnologia SOAP ou RestFull com PHP, JAVA entre outras.

Veja um exemplo aqui.

https://trinitytuts.com/build-first-web-service-php/

Comment: Pela pesquisa que fiz, acho que posso deixar como está, o site será feito com MVC, daí é só alterar os Controller para retornar array os json de acordo com a origem da requisição.